# How do I set up MySql workbench to be used with laravel?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I'm really new to using Ubuntu. During university we used MySql Workbench as our way of interacting with the databases we would seed in Laravel and I'm looking recreate this on my own PC. How do I go about installing and configuring workbench to be used with my Laravel projects? I had it (workbench) installed but it doesn't seem to 'connect' to Laravel. Apologies if that doesn't really make sense but I'm new to a lot of this and it's a little intimidating.

Do i need to install SQL on it's own then configure workbench to work with it? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

For installation of MySQL it should be as simple as `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.
To use the DB in your laravel project you just need to specify it's settings in your `.env` file (DB_HOST would be 127.0.0.1 if your DB is local, and then DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD).

Comment: What about using  mysql workbench though? same process?

Comment: After the installation you should be able to run the workbench from your terminal with `mysql-workbench`

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Update your env settings and see below how to set connection in workbench:

[image: connection settings]

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=DBNAME
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```